# Why do the file size differ in the adf run and the actual file?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I just loaded 1gb of file from sftp to adls gen2. so in the pipeline run i can see the data read and data written to be 1.007GB(compressed) but when I look at the actual file in the ADLS, it is only 960mb.
This is the same case with a 2.3GB(compressed) file, in adls it is only 2.18GB.

The pipeline runs fine, succeeds infact. What is the reason to see this. is there any data loss?

Comment: ADF compresses the content before sending it to the recipient using a compression algorithm. Depending on the sort of data and the compression algorithm employed, the compressed file size may be smaller or bigger than the uncompressed file size.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar scenario in my environment in data factory run its showing 18.055 kb  but in ADLS its giving me 17.63 kb. as per below:

- Data factory run:
  [image]
- ADLS:
  [image]

**But I found no data loss.**

The reason for this might be.

- The size of files can be decreased during the transmission procedure thanks to the built-in compression features of ADF. As a result, the file size indicated during the ADF process might not be the full size of the file.
- The file may be changed to a different encoding during the upload procedure if it uses a character encoding other than the usual character encoding used by ADF or includes non-ASCII characters.

It's crucial to understand that there may not always be an issue if the real file size differs from the ADF run. It's always a good idea to confirm that the file was transmitted properly and that all the required information was included, though.